# ElasticSearch Scripting: check if array contains a value

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's say I have created a document like this:

```
PUT idx/type/1
{
   "the_field": [1,2,3]
}
```

I can retrieve my document using GET /idx/type/1:

```
{
   "_index": "idx",
   "_type": "type",
   "_id": "1",
   "_version": 1,
   "found": true,
   "_source": {
      "the_field": [
         1,
         2,
         3
      ]
   }
}
```

Now, I want to check if the field "the_field" contains the value 2.
I know I can use a term clause, but I need to check this using a filter script, so I tried:

```
POST /idx/typ/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    }, 
    "filter": {
        "script": {
           "script": "doc['the_field'].values.contains(2)"
        }
    }
}
```

and get no results:

```
{
   "took": 6,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 0,
      "max_score": null,
      "hits": []
   }
}
```

To test if my mevl script syntax is right, I tried doing this:

```
POST /idx/type/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    }, 
    "filter": {
        "script": {
           "script": "[1,2,3].contains(3)"
        }
    }
}
```

and get the right results:

```
{
   "took": 1,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "idx",
            "_type": "type",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "the_field": [
                  1,
                  2,
                  3
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

I think doc['the_field'].values should return [1,2,3], is not it? If so, my code should work.

Does anybody can help me?
Thank you!

**UPDATE**

When I replace all the [1, 2, 3] in my code with ["a"," b", "c"], it works. Any idea?

Comment: Unrelated, but why are you using `POST` for the searches?

Comment: Because I think that browsers do not support GET requests with a body.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is working with "a", "b", "c" because `the_field` is being stored in Elasticsearch by default as a string and not an integer. You can validate by checking the mapping with:

```
 $ curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/idx/type/_mapping'
```

The following should set the appropriate field type:

```
 $ curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/idx/type/_mapping' -d '
 {
    "type" : {
        "properties" : {
            "the_field" : {"type" : "integer" }
         }
     }
 }
```

Update the mapping, re-index your data and see if that works. Please see the [PUT Mapping API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html) for additional guidance if needed.